# parse error on input `=' - Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Im getting this really annoying error in when I run this Haskell code. For some reason it doesn't like the fist line `delLast :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]`

```
delLast :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
delLast [] = []
delLast (x:[]) = []
delLast (x:xs) = [x] ++ delLast xs
```

Doest anyone know why Im getting this error? Thanks.

This is the error that I get:

```
parse error on input `='
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: What is the error the compiler outputs?

Comment: I just added the output error

Comment: There is no error in code you posted.

Comment: Thats the problem. However every time I compile I keep getting this error and I dont know why.

Comment: Failing to reproduce, please consider posting compiler command line and full output.

Comment: Any unicode control characters inside?

Comment: The `Ord` constraint isn't needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is there an unterminated definition immediately before that line?

```
x = do

delLast :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
delLast [] = []
delLast (x:[]) = []
delLast (x:xs) = [x] ++ delLast xs
```

Compiling that gives me:

```
test.hs:5:12: parse error on input `='
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
delLast [] = []
delLast xs = init xs
```

or if you want to do it your way but better

```
delLast :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
delLast [] = []  
delLast [x] = []                  -- Looks better IMO
delLast (x:xs) = x : delLast xs   -- : instead of ++ gives a performance boost
```